# Oracle SQL order by doesn't order multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have a table `student` and I want to sort three columns in it: `first_name, last_name, street_address`. I'm expecting a result like this:

```
| first_name | last_name | street_address |

     A            A        100 Carroll St
     B            B        200 Carroll St
     C            C        300 Carroll St
```

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, street_address
FROM student
ORDER BY first_name, last_name, street_address;
```

But this query sorts like this:

```
| first_name | last_name        | street_address            |

     A         C (not sorted)       300 Carroll St  (not sorted)
     B         B (not sorted)       100 Carroll St  (not sorted)
     C         A (not sorted)       200 Carroll St  (not sorted)
```

This query doesn't work as supposed to. It doesn't sort all columns in ascending order, it only sorts the first column which appears after ORDER BY. As mentioned above, the query only sorts `first_name` column. If I change the places of columns after ORDER BY, it only sorts first mentioned column after "ORDER_BY".

I have searched Google and many forums and couldn't find anything related to this problem.

Oracle version:

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production              0

PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production                                                    0

CORE    12.2.0.1.0      Production                                                                0

TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production                                   0

NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production                                                    0

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: That is how `order by` works.  Keys are used in order, and only to break ties in preceding keys.

Comment: Exactly as expected. First sort by first_name. In cases of duplicates sort by last_name. Etc.

Comment: These aren't independent values; columns belong to rows, so you can't sort first name separately from last name separately from street address. Well, you *could*, but the question is what would such a data represent.

Comment: That's how a order by works...

Comment: @APC Ahh yes, good point, reread the question, I will delete that comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some sample input data, which I hope will make the following explanation clearer:

```
id  | first_name | last_name    | street_address         
 10 | Albert     |  Camus       | 300 Carroll St 
 20 | Caroline   |  Aherne      | 200 Carroll St 
 30 | Bertoldt   |  Brecht      | 500 Carroll St  
 40 | Albert     |  Dumbledore  | 400 Carroll St 
 50 | Bertoldt   |  Brecht      | 100 Carroll St
```

Here we have five **records**, which tell us useful things, like Albert Camus lives at 300 Carroll Street and Caroline Ahern lives at 200 Carroll St. The important thing to understand about a SQL query is that it retrieves records; when we use ORDER BY it sorts the records, not the individual columns.

So when we sort these records ordering by `first_name, last_name, street_address` we get this result:

```
id  | first_name | last_name    | street_address         
 10 | Albert     |  Camus       | 300 Carroll St 
 40 | Albert     |  Dumbledore  | 400 Carroll St 
 50 | Bertoldt   |  Brecht      | 100 Carroll St  
 30 | Bertoldt   |  Brecht      | 500 Carroll St 
 20 | Caroline   |  Aherne      | 200 Carroll St
```

The result set is the table's records sorted into `first_name` order; when two records have the same value `first_name` the sort uses `last_name` to break the tie; when both `first_name` and  `last_name` are the same the sort uses `street_address`. This is exactly what we would expect. The records remain intact.

What would it mean to sort the columns independently? There is no such person as Albert Aherne living at 100 Carroll Street. So how would SQL make one up?

If you still quite can't get the way this works, notice that I added a surrogate primary key to the table. The ID column uniquely identifies each record. So ID = 30 identifies the Bertoldt Brecht who lives at 500 Carroll St. Supposing ORDER BY worked the way you expect: what would the value of ID be for Albert Aherne living at 100 Carroll Street?

---

> According to the normalization forms, in a table, all records must be related to the primary key and it means you can't sort multiple columns then why we need sorting multiple columns?

Normalisation has nothing to do with it. We might want to order by columns of a compound key or even by non-key attributes. In such circumstances we often need to order by multiple columns.

For instance, I shuffle a deck of cards. Now I ask you to take five cards and put them in ascending order, aces low. Easy enough. Except that you drew the seven of spades and the seven of hearts. Which comes first? Spades is higher than hearts, so seven of hearts then seven of spades. But both before nine of clubs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it's clear to me. I didn't think logically. But there is another question, where we can use sorting multiple columns. According to the normalization forms, in a table, all records must be related to the primary key and it means you can't sort multiple columns then why we need sorting multiple columns?

Comment: Expanded my answer to address your follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

The query you've given won't give the results you stated. What you'd get would be

```
A   A   100 Carroll St
B   B   200 Carroll St
C   C   300 Carroll St
```

using the following query

```
WITH student AS (SELECT 'A' AS FIRST_NAME, 'A' AS LAST_NAME, '100 Carroll St' AS STREET_ADDRESS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'B', 'B', '200 Carroll St' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'C', 'C', '300 Carroll St' FROM DUAL)
SELECT first_name, last_name, street_address
FROM student
ORDER BY first_name, last_name, street_address
```

I suggest you go back and look at the actual data in the table, which may not be what you expected.

Best of luck.